# Ajax success function with python: odd behavior

Tags: python, ajax, post

I found an odd behavior when trying to use data on the browser-side, which is sent by a python script client-side.

The ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    type: "POST",
    url: "/path/cgi-bin/pyscript.py",
    data: JSON.stringify(my_array), 
    dataType: "html",
    success : function(data) {
        document.getElementById("ajaxAnchor").innerHTML = data + "Some random string to test display"
    }
});
```

}

I wanted to send back to `data` the result of a `print()` in the python script, but this only works in an unusually specific case. For the printed data to be sent back, there must first exist a `print()` executed with an `\n` at the end.

```
  print("This line won't be sent to browser but is necessary \n")
  print("This text will be sent back")
```

And it's not just about adding the line break, because the following example won't work:

```
  print("\n This text will not be sent back")
```

There must be a "wasted" line for the following ones to be sent succesfully:

```
  print("This line won't be sent to browser but is necessary")
  print("\n This text will be sent back")
```

I'm a beginner in using Ajax, so if anyone would care to explain why this happens, I'd like to understand the underlying logic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the CGI-Protokoll. You have to first send an HTTP-Header, which is terminated by a empty line. An minimal answer would be:

```
print("200 OK\n")
print("Your Text.")
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. Looking into the CGI protocol, I found some explanation on _why_ the first line is necessary [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_cgi_programming.htm), although interestingly, it doesn't matter whether or not the line actually contains a useful HTTP-header specifying the content type (e.g. Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n).